# Op Amp balancing impedances

Tags: operational-amplifier, circuit-analysis

I know that I should balance input impedances in opamp circuits to avoid input bias currents from causing unwanted behaviour. I can understand how to do this in simple cases, but not in more complex cases. For example, in the case of a simple inverting amplifier, R3 should be added and made equal to R1//R2 (R1 in parallel with R2) if my understanding is correct:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fsNbiW.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

But what should I do in more complex cases, such as this:
[image: 2 opamp circuit]

I would think that I should put a resistor to ground on the 'fb' node and it should be 5.1k//10k. But what should I do with the other amplifier? How do I balance those filter impedances without changing the corner frequency of those filters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The purpose of this matching is to minimize DC offset due to bias current. If the op-amp has low bias current and the application is not sensitive to offset, you don't necessarily need to match the DC resistance. You can calculate the offset using the bias/leakage current figure from the op-amp datasheet.

In this case, if you want to change the impedance looking out of the U1 inverting terminal to 10k, it would be pretty easy. Just change R1 and R2 to 10k, and change C1 and C2 to 1nF. This will not change the corner frequency, but it will increase the input impedance on "in."

Since it is a DC phenomenon, the matching applies to the DC resistance only.

Comment: Or add 18k in series with U1's non-inverting input. Then both sides will see 20k. The R for the fb node is 5.1k//10k = 3.4k -- put it in series with that non-inverting input (not to GND).